# Is wooden worktop oil safe for cats?

Tags: cats, poison

I'm considering wooden worktops when in replace my kitchen, which will need regular oiling with this or something similar: [Rustins Danish Oil.](https://www.rustins.ltd/rustins/our-products/indoor/danish-oil)

While I'm pretty sure it will be safe when dry, I can't find any information about whether it's safe for cats while it's drying (inevitably my little monsters will walk across it and it's not possible to exclude them from the room).

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to not allow any pets in the kitchen while it's drying, you may just have to isolate them in a room (with all necessities) until drying is complete.

From the [MSDS](https://www.rustins.ltd/images/files/1135-SDS-DANISH%20OIL%201_SDS.pdf)

> **Most important adverse effects:** Repeated exposure may cause skin dryness or cracking. Contains cobalt 6, methyl ethyl
>   ketoxime, 2-octyl-2h-isothiazol-3-one. May produce an allergic reaction. Flammable
>   liquid and vapour. May cause drowsiness or dizziness. May cause an allergic skin
>   reaction. Toxic to aquatic life with long lasting effects.

Although this is for people it is better to err on the side of caution, mammalian skin can react fairly similarly to products like this.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have this mixture on the surfaces in my kitchen. Cobalt may cause heart and liver damage if ingested in doses only little greater than recommended for prolonged periods.